# WTRN0006W for liberty on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a long-running REST method on a Bluemix Liberty runtime and I am getting the WTRN0006W error message because the method takes more than 120 seconds to return. However, it's a single-user app, this method is expected to take long and there's no database data to persist. So it's OK to set the timeout to N minutes in this case.

The problem is that I can' t find exactly what file and how to change the file using the Bluemix Liberty profile in order to do that (increase the timeout).

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The file to modify is server.xml.  See this blog post on [Custom Liberty server.xml configurations in IBM Bluemix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/01/06/modify-liberty-server-xml-configurations-ibm-bluemix/).  Then, try configuration like:

```
<server>
    ...
    <transaction totalTranLifetimeTimeout="5m"/>
```

See the [Transaction Manager (transaction)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_transaction.html) topic in the Knowledge Center for other transaction configuration options.